# How can I use in query in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

If the data in my mongodb is like this

```
{
    "category": "Pop Culture",
    "subcategory": "Film Directors",
    "name": "Quentin Tarantino",
}
```

Is there any way I can find this object only using some part of the name

Like:

```
db.data.find_one({'name': 'quentin'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `string` data, you can use `$regex` operator to find with some part of the field data.

**Example:**

```js
db.collection.findOne({
  name: {
    $regex: "Some part of name"
  }
})
```

> See [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) for more information.